# ngOnInit not subscribing to event observable

Tags: angular, typescript, angular6, angular-router

I'm dealing with a problem I've not been able to solve so far.
The thing is. I have a component called `HeaderComponent`, a service called `TabChangingService` and another component called `TabsComponent`. In the `HeaderComponent` I've got three buttons and each of these buttons have the following click method.

```
click(tab: number) {
    this.tabChangingService.changeTab(tab);
    this.router.navigate(['/tabs'])
}
```

And, in the `ngOnInit` method of `TabsComponent` is the following:

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.tabChangingService.tab.pipe(
   tap(tab => this.tab = tab),
   tap(tab => console.log('setting tab ', tab) // added this linte
  ).subscribe();
}
```

And in the template I have the following code:

```
<ng-container [ngSwitch]="tab">
  <div id="tab1" *ngSwitchCase="0">content...</div>
  <div id="tab2" *ngSwitchCase="1">content...</div>
</ng-container>
```

The code of the service is the following:

```
export class TabChangingService {

  private _tab = new Subject<number>();

  constructor() {

  }

  public changeTab(tab: number) {
    console.log('Changing to tab ', tab); // added this line
    this._tab.next(tab);
  }

  public get tab() {
    return this._tab;
  }

}
```

But when I click one of the buttons of the header component, the tab does not get selected. Only after I click a second time the tab gets selected. As you could notice, the tabs component is in another route, and I don't know this is happening because the component doesn't get mounted the moment I click the button for the first time or something, but I hope you can help me. Thanks in advance, really appreciate your help.

**EDIT**
When I click one of the buttons on the header for first time, `Changing tab` is printed, however, `Setting tab` doesn't. `Setting tab` isn't printed until I click the second time.

Comment: What is `this.tabChangingService.tab` ?

Comment: I added the code of the service, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

### Try setTimeout

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.tabChangingService.tab.pipe(
   tap(tab => {
      setTimeout(()=>{   
        this.tab = tab
      }, 1);
   })
  ).subscribe();
}
```

> Just increase the timeout duration to check if it is Component initialization issue.

Comment: Ok, I'll try it soon. Thank you so much for helping :)

Comment: Did you increase the timeout duration and tested ?

Comment: Yes, I did, I increased to 500. That's the maximum I can set.

Comment: GIve a try `NgZone`.  ` this.ngZone.run(() => {
          this.router.navigateByUrl('/path');
        });`

Comment: Ok, thanks in advance, I'll try as soon as I'm done with something else. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

in your tab changing service add this..

```
private _tab = new Subject<number>();
tabChanged = this._tab.asObservable();
```

and in your ngOnInit(), add this..

```
ngOnInit() {
 this.tabChangingService.tabChanged.subscribe(
   // add your code here.
 );
```

You have not mentioned if those components have any kind of relationship between them. but that should not matter since you have a service. You forgot to initialize your variable to Observable.

I have showed in the code of what I have understood about Observables and Subject interactions. Please correct me if am wrong in the words that I have written above.

Comment: Ok, I'll try that soon. Thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

I ended up solving the problem with a `setTimeout` like Sunil suggested. But, the `setTimeout` was not used in the `TabsComponent` but in the `HeaderComponent` at the moment of emitting the selected value, like this:

```
click(tab: number) {
 setTimeout(() => {
    this.tabChangingService.changeTab(tab);
   },
   500
 )
 // rest of the code
}
```

Thanks to every one for the help :D